# How to write regular expression that has any combination of two keywords?

Tags: regex, spam-prevention

I'm writing a spam filter in regular expression syntax.  I want to filter out any email that tries to spam hair growing products.  So if the message has of these two words in any combination, even apart, of hair and grow, I want to filter it. It needs to be case insensitive.  For example, often I seen in the message

...regrow....hair

Grow....HAIR...

--re-grow...hair

---hair....grow...

...regrow...your-hair...

Basically, I'm looking to write a filter to catch certain keywords appearing in conjunction somewhere in the message.  If I see the word grow used in conjunction with the word hair then it's most likely some sort hair boldness spam and should be filtered.

So the same type of filter can be apply to other keyword combinations.  Like bold and hair, penis and enlarge, etc.

These spammers are very clever, they don't put the exact words together and they will use dash or capitalization or reword the order to throw spam filters off.

So far I'm unable to come up with an ideal way writing such spam filter in regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pattern with positive lookaheads which would fire upon hitting any of the matching keywords, e.g.

```
^(?=.*(?:re-?)?[Gg]row)(?=.*(?:your-)?hair).*$
```

### Demo

This pattern is just a rough example to set you on the right path.  You may want to do things like add additional logic, or use it in case insensitive mode.

Comment: That's great, but I how do I make it catch uppercase as well?  The demo show that it did not catch GROW...HAIR.

Comment: @GH It really depends on the language/tool you are using, which you never told us.  In the absence of this, my answer is reasonable.

Comment: I'm using SpamCombat (https://www.glocksoft.com/spamcombat/).  The product has a Whitelist & Blacklist feature that allows me to filter spams using regular expression.  I came up with this for case insensitive keyword

\b(?i)(?<= |^)(grow)(?= |$)

And it seem to work.  But, am having trouble combining what you have to mine.

Comment: What you have looks nothing like what I have.  Just try adding `(?i)` at the beginning of the pattern I gave you.